# Range Error Maximum call stack size exceeded Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I want to add machine detail and buton bar to my app, and this is what happens. I've used it in other parts aswell and it worked fine, only in core module are the errors.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNwaT.png)

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

core module (error appears when I add "IfaButtonModule" or "MachineModule")

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TakePhotoComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ShareMachineComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WebcamModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    IfaButtonModule,
    MachineModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TakePhotoComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ShareMachineComponent,
    NotificationsComponent
  ],
  providers: [NgxImageCompressService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

button-module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IfaButtonBarItemComponent,
    IfaButtonBarComponent,
    IfaButtonBarGroupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    IfaButtonBarComponent,
    IfaButtonBarGroupComponent,
    IfaButtonBarItemComponent
  ]
})
export class IfaButtonModule { }
```

machine module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MachineListComponent,
    MachineDetailEditComponent,
    MachineDetailComponent,
    MachineListItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    IfaButtonModule,
    OperationModeModule,
    ProtectionModule,
    ManipulationModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatMenuModule,
    MachineDetailEditComponent,
    MachineListComponent,
    MachineDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class MachineModule {

}
```

the html that uses the components: (inside the core module area)

```
<ng-container>
  <app-machine-detail [machine]="completeMachine">
  </app-machine-detail>
  <app-ifa-button-bar-group>
    <app-ifa-button-bar-item [label]="'MISC.BACK'" (click)="navigateBack()">
    </app-ifa-button-bar-item>
  </app-ifa-button-bar-group>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because you import `CoreModule` in the `MachineModule` and the `MachineModule` in the `CoreModule`. This should not happen, you should re-work your module dependencies and fix the circular import. `IfaButtonModule` has the exact same issue.

Comment: I removed the core module from both of the other modules and still get the same error.

Comment: Check for more circular dependencies then. Maybe other module that you import into these imports the CoreModule. `OperationModeModule`, `ProtectionModule` and `ManipulationModule` should also *not* import the `CoreModule`.